# Jackson @JsonSubType Structure check

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have Classes like below:

```java
public class Car{
   
   String name;

   Short type;

   @JsonTypeInfo(property = "type", include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
   @JsonSubTypes({
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=A.class , name = "1"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=B.class , name = "2"),
    })
   Object o;
   
}

public class A{
   String foo;
}

public class B{
   String foo;
   String bar;
}
```

When i send wrong `JSON` structure like:

```json
{
"name": "John" ,
"type": 1 ,
"o": {
   "foo": "fooValue",
   "bar": "barValue"

}
```

I expect to get `Jackson` `MismatchedInputException` but It do not raise exception.
Jackson set o as A class and set `foo` property value to `fooValue`.

I used `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false)` too but it did not work.
Any body have suggession?